# Laravel Passing Json Data to View Error

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am trying to pass json data and want to print in the view , but I get the error as

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myapi\resources\views\contacts.blade.php)

Here is the code I am using. The Pages controller have the following function to call an API and get the data in JSON format.

```
public function contacts(){

        //$rs =  file_get_contents("http://someurl.com");
        $url ="http://someurl.com/ac/get";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return view('contacts')->with('leads' ,json_decode($data, true));
      }
```

The API is returning data like :

```
[    
    {  
        "id":"16828",
        "first_name":"Ray",
        "last_name":"Smith",
        "email":"ray@smith.com",
        "phone":"123456789",
        "date_added":"2017-12-12 13:32:30"
    },
    {  
        "id":"13161",
        "first_name":"Lou",
        "last_name":"Spa",
        "email":"lou@some.com",
        "phone":"982345678",
        "date_added":"2017-12-01 13:25:33"
    }
]
```

In my view I want to print all the leads:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<H3>Contacts </H3>
 @foreach ($leads as $key => $user)
     {{ $user["id"] }}
     {{ $user["name"] }}
     {{ $user["email"] }}
 @endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: seems like your `$leads` is empty. Are you sure that your $data is correct ?

Comment: what you have in `var_dump(json_decode($data, true))`?

Comment: @ArtOsi I am new in Laravel this is the first project I am trying, where I can put this var_dump(json_decode($data, true)) in the View or the controller?

Comment: if I am doing this from the controller : public function emails(){
        return view('emails')->with('email' , 'stacy@gmail.com');
    } and then in view @section('content')
<div class="container">
{{email}}
</div>
@endsection  it says  "Use of undefined constant email - assumed "'email'

Comment: put it before `return view('contacts')->with('leads' ,json_decode($data, true));`

Comment: @ArtOsi  My bad. yes the data was empty. I have corrected that. Thanks

Comment: you're welcome =) always check if you get data you are expecting to get before proceeding